# Uiswitch with On/Off Image in Xamarin.ios _ Solution in Xamarin required

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiswitch

I want a switch that has an on and an off image. I know the control is deprecated but if anyone can share a custom control or a workaround which looks like a switch.

Comment: Can't you just use a transparent button, that switches between two images? I mean it's not great because it wouldn't necessarily be animated, but it'd work.

Comment: `UISwitch` is not deprecated, it is the `OnImage` and `OffImage` methods that were NOP'd in iOS7+.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt I can but animation is required

Comment: @SushiHangover yes the switch is not but the on off image is not working. I would be a great help if you can share workaround. Thanks

Comment: You don't have a lot of options really, if it's just colour, then you can use the on Tint property to change the colour, otherwise it's a case of creating your own control with custom animations.